# Count number of Paragraphs excluding spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently working on a code to count the number of paragraphs. The only issue I have not been able to resolve is that spaces inbetween each paragraphs is also been counted. For instance, below example should return 3 but rather it returns 5 because of the empty carriage returns.

```
sentence 123
sentence 234


sentence 345
```

[Full Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahRHC/)

Is there a regex combination that can resolve this or must I write a conditional statement. Thanks

Comment: a typo: "count the number of paragraphs in a sentence" => "count the number of spaces in a sentence"?

Comment: Sentences do not contain paragraphs. Does the the phrase, " looking for number of non empty lines in a block of text" fit what you're after?

Comment: What you're really doing here is counting the number of _nonempty lines_ in a block of text.  Lines are typically considered sequences of 0 or more characters ( 1 or more if nonempty) followed by a newline.  Paragraphs are a fuzzier concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude blank lines explicitly:

```
function nonblank(line) {
    return ! /^\s*$/.test(line);
}

.. the_result_of_the_split.filter(nonblank).length ..
```

Modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qq38a/

Answer (score 2):

You can change your regexp a liitle:

```
.split(/[\r\n]+/)
```

[`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus) character in regexp

> matches the preceding character 1 or more times. Equivalent to {1,}.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ahRHC/1/

### UPD

Improved solution would use another regexp using negative lookahead:

```
`/[\r\n]+(?!\s*$)/`
```

This means: match new lines and carriage returns only if they are not followed by any number of white space characters and the end of line.

#### Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/ahRHC/2/

### UPD 2 Final

To prevent regexp from becoming too complicated and solve the problem of leading new lines, there is another solution using `$.trim` before splitting a value:

```
function counter(field) {
    var val = $.trim($(field).val());
    var lineCount = val ? val.split(/[\r\n]+/).length : 0;
    jQuery('.paraCount').text(lineCount);
}
```

#### Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/ahRHC/3/

Comment: close , but this still counts extra empty lines once after each nonempty line.  Try with <kbd>one line of text\n\n\ntwo lines of text\n\n\n</kbd> - you'll get 3.

Comment: Updated answer still counts leading blank line.